# Localizar uma string

Tags: javascript

Eu possuo a seguinte função em JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {

  var extPermitidas = ['txt'];
  var extArquivo = this.value.split('.').pop();

  if(typeof extPermitidas.find(function(ext){ return extArquivo == ext; }) == 'undefined') {
    alert('O arquivo não pode ser validado pois possui extenção não permitida!');
    return;
  } else {
    var file = this.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){


      // By lines
      var lines = this.result.split('\n');
      for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
          console.log(lines[line]);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
  alert('Arquivo validado com sucesso!');
}});
```

Se eu possuo um arquivo com linhas mais ou menos assim:

N3019283746536 9938 QUALQUER COISA
N41092832938 01982108 81902

E eu desejo por exemplo verificar se seus 2 primeiros elementos são N3 se o tamanho de sua linha possui 32 caracteres, como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue com o método `.susbtr(0,2)` (primeiros dois caracteres) e com `.length` (retorna o tamanho da string).

Seria:

```
if(lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N3" && lines[line].length == 32){
   // atendeu às condições
}
```

Note que usei o operador `&&` que tornam obrigatórias as duas condições do `if`.

Comment: Quer dizer que se eu precisasse da N4 e da N3 válidas eu precisaria colocar a N4 no mesmo if?

Comment: É que cada N possui uma quantidade de caracteres diferentes, isso alteraria pra algo como: if( (lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N3" && lines[line].length == 32 ) || (lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N4" && lines[line].lenght == 30){   por exemplo?

Comment: Só faltou um `)` no final pra fechar o if: `if( (lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N3" && lines[line].length == 32 ) || (lines[line].substr(0,2) == "N4" && lines[line].lenght == 30) ){`

Comment: Por que o substr é (0,2) e não (0,1)?

Comment: Pq vc quer pegar os 2 primeiros caracteres. O `0,1` irá pegar só o primeiro.